# How is a h264 idea bitstream organized? / header start codes

Tags: video, video-encoding, h.264, mpeg-4, bitstream

I was trying to learn a bit about h264 by looking at the bitstream of a video file with a hex editor. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622326/how-to-overwrite-i-frames-of-a-video) the start codes for a video object planes (0x000001b6) and for i-frames (0x000001b600).

But I can't find many of those bytes in video files. Most of the time those start codes appear at the beginning of a file with only a few bites in between. I expected them to show up very regularly, in equal distance all over the file!?

Is is even ok to look at a file with a hex editor this way? What other start codes exist and how is a h264 file organised?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `0x000001b6` start code applies to mpeg-4 part 2 video which is the simple profile.  This corresponds to codecs such as XVID and DIVX.  H.264 is mpeg-4 part 10 which is the advanced video coding profile. H.264 uses different start codes.

I am not as familiar with part 10 as I am with part 2, but a brief look through the standard (ISO 14496-10) shows that the bitstream is broken into sections called NAL units.  These units have the 24 bit code `0x000001` preceding them for synchronization as per section B.1.1.  The following byte is made up of the fields `forbidden_zero_bit`, `nal_ref_idc`, and `nal_unit_type` as per section 7.3.1.

I am not sure whether these NAL units are separated on frame boundaries or not.  You may just have to get a hold of the standard that lays out all of the bitstream syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I started looking into mpeg4 part2 instead since I just wanted to get an brief overview of how mpeg4 works bitstream wise! Thanks again!