# ffmpeg - can we apply a light-weight partial encryption algorithm to I-frames of a video file?

Tags: c#, java

your suggestions are most welcome.
 I want to do partial encryption for the compressed video file. I want to encrypt only the I-frames not the headers. The output required is unwatchable video. For this application, I followed the link [How to overwrite i-frames of a video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622326/how-to-overwrite-i-frames-of-a-video.(really), thanks for this link). Is it right if I followed the steps:

1. copying the I-frames to a file using **ffmpeg -i filename -an -vcodec copy -f rawvideo output_filename**. I also need audio data. Should I remove **_an** option to achieve this?
2. exracting the start code (c++ codings given in the link are not working for me but I am trying. java codings to extract the start code are preferred) and encrypting the i-frame data and stored it in a new file.
3. I don't know how can I insert the modified  i-frame data to the original file?Is there any ffmpeg command or can we write the coding using libavformat and libavcodec? code snippets will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.